# JavaScript Errorhandling with ES6

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I'm taking a course in Udemy to learn how to code in JavaSricpt

The code the Teacher use and he use module.export and require but in ES6 you must use exprot and import

```
    module.exports=(err, req, res, next) => {
      console.log(err.stack);
      err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
      err.status = err.status || 'error';
    
      res.status(err.statusCode).json({
        status: err.statusCode,
        message: err.message,
      });
    };
```

This code I need to transform form old code to ES6

how can I make this to work?

Error:

```
    throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
          ^

TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
```

errorConroller script

```
    export function globalErrorHandler (err, req, res, next) {
      console.log(err.stack);
      err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
      err.status = err.status || 'error';
    
      res.status(err.statusCode).json({
        status: err.statusCode,
        message: err.message,
      });
    };
```

appError.js

```
class AppError extends Error{
    constructor(message,statusCode){
        super(message);
        
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.status = `${statusCode}`.startsWith('4') ? 'failed': 'error';
        this.isOperation = true;

        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.construct);
    }
}

export default AppError;
```

App script

```
import express, { json } from 'express';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

import tourRouter from './routes/tourRoutes.js';
import userRouter from './routes/userRoutes.js';
import AppError from './utils/appError.js';
import * as globalErrorHandler from './controller/errorController.js';
import morgan from 'morgan';

//Load file
 const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

// const tours = JSON.parse(
//   fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/dev-data/data/tours-simple.json`)
// );
const app = express();
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

// const tourRouter = express.Router();

// Middleware
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.requstTime = new Date().toISOString();
  next();
});

//Load modules and routes
app.use('/api/v1/tours', tourRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);

/**
 * A handler for routes that don't exist
 */
app.all('*', (req,res, next)=>{
  next(new AppError(`Can't find ${req.originalUrl} on this server!`,404));
});


app.use(globalErrorHandler);

export default app;
```

What do I need to do fix this?
Hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks

When I use poste man I should get JSON object with the error, get the error writen in body text under Error:. Hope someone can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

```
export function globalErrorHandler (err, req, res, next) {
```

```
import { globalErrorHandler } from './controller/errorController.js';
```

or

```
export default function globalErrorHandler (err, req, res, next) {
```

```
import globalErrorHandler from './controller/errorController.js';
```